# Disable Shibboleth-Omniauth Debug Mode

Tags: apache, gitlab, omniauth, shibboleth

I have Installed Gitlab EE with Apache2 and Shibboleth. Configuration is working fine and I get all data I need for authentification I think. I set debug to false in gitlab.rb but I always get the folwing message with the sso callback. Am I missing something? Where do I have to set debug to false?

```
!!!!! This message is generated by omniauth-shibboleth. To remove it set :debug to false. !!!!!
HTTP_ACCEPT: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: gzip, deflate
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,it;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5
HTTP_AFFILIATION: ....
...
```

This is part of my gitlab Config:

```
gitlab_rails['omniauth_providers'] = [
  {
    "name" => 'shibboleth',
        "args" => {
        "debug" => "false",
        "shib_session_id_field" => "HTTP_SHIB_SESSION_ID",
        "shib_application_id_field" => "HTTP_SHIB_APPLICATION_ID",
        "uid_field" => 'HTTP_UID',
        "name_field" => 'HTTP_DISPLAYNAME',
        "info_fields" => { "email" => 'HTTP_EMAIL'}
        }
  }
]
```